# Spring Mongo reactive Handle Database Error on Save

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux

Can someone please help me as how do i handle database exception when i use Reactive Mongo with Spring webflux ...

I have a 
Repository class

```
public interface UserRepository  extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User,String> 
{
   public Mono<User> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Handler method in UserHandler

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> saveUser(ServerRequest request) {

    Mono<User> user = request.bodyToMono(User.class).map(userObj -> {
        userObj.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userObj.getPassword()));
        return userObj;
    });

    return 
     ServerResponse.ok().body(this.userRepository.insert(user),User.class);
}
```

I have defined a unique key on username so when the exception throw i want to return a meaningful message to use how can i use OnErrorMap to return a server reponse with message.

I get the below error in console but no error returned to the user

```
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: letsbuy.users index: username dup key: { : "asoni11" }
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl$8.onResult(MongoCollectionImpl.java:638) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.4.3.jar:na]
    ... 163 common frames omitted

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit counterintuitive, but in that case you need to do something like:

```
Mono<User> savedUser = request.bodyToMono(User.class).map(userObj -> {
        userObj.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userObj.getPassword()));
        return userObj;
    })
    .flatMap(user -> this.userRepository.insert(user));

    return savedUser
            .flatMap(u -> ServerResponse.ok().syncBody(u))
            .onErrorResume(DuplicateKeyException.class,
                    t -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).syncBody(t.getMessage()));
```

Comment: Thanks one more question is this code throws DuplicateKeyException as i have a unique constraint on username field but the error is not return back as a response so how can i sent the custom error message to the user

Comment: Thanks but in Postman when i call the API i still get INTERNAL SERVER Error and no message

Comment: Could you edit your question to reflect that? A stacktrace and the error response could be useful

Comment: Done the error in console is  
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: letsbuy.users index: username dup key: { : "asoni11" }

Comment: Then you should use that MongoWriteException instead in the onErrorResume method

Comment: Same thing INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR even if i use the MongoWriteException

Comment: Just fixed my sample, got an operator wrong which turned things into a `Mono<Mono<User>>` at some point. Also, watch out to `import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;`, and not the one provided by the mongo library, because that's what spring data is throwing

Comment: One last thing: your model is missing a `@Indexed(unique=true)` on the userName attribute.

Comment: Can you share your code sample .. for me still same error (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR ) in the POSTMAN when i call the API even after doing  the changes as you suggested